# How to update an ion-slide after removing an Item?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a list of cards in ion-slide, and each card has a close icon to remove it.

```
    <ion-slides >
                <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of cart; let i = index" >
                    <ion-card>
              
                      <ion-img  src='close.png'    (click)="removeData(item)" ></ion-img>                        
                  </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>
              </ion-slides>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
async removeData(object) {
    .......
      // get the index of object 
this.dataservice.removeItem(index);
        .....
        }
```

**DataServiceService.service.ts**

```
removeItem(index) {
    return this.getAllItems().then((result) => {
      if (result) {
        result.splice(index, 1);
        return this.storage.set('i', result);
      }
    });
  }
```

When a card is removed, I want the list to be updated or the current page to be refreshed. I tried in the removeItem function
`"this.router.navigate(["/home"]);"` but nothing changed, and `"window.location.reload();"` reloads all pages starting with login.
Could you please suggest a solution to the problem?

Comment: pass index in removeData and check this code `this.cart[index]. splice(index,1)`

Comment: @RaviAshara Can you please write it as an answer? to be able to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by using splice

```
   this.cart.splice(index, 1);
```